# flutter - A value of type 'List<data>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<data>'

Tags: flutter

currently building a news app in flutter. In my database file, i've got a method to get all my news and turn them into a list so i can show them on the home screen. In my home screen, i've got an empty list of news, but when i try to affect the list from the database to this variable, it says a cast is needed but the error message is telling me that they are literally the same type

readAllNews method :

```
Future<List<IRLNews>> readAllNews() async {
final db = await instance.database;
// final result =
//     await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $tableNotes ORDER BY $orderBy');

final result = await db.query(tableIRLnews);

return result.map((json) => IRLNews.fromJson(json)).toList();


}
```

homescreen :

```
    class IRLNewsPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _IRLNewsPageState createState() => _IRLNewsPageState();
}

class _IRLNewsPageState extends State<IRLNewsPage> {
  late List<IRLNews> newsList;
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    refreshNews();
  }

  Future refreshNews() async {
    setState(() => isLoading = true);

    this.newsList = await UniverseDatabase.instance.readAllNews();

    setState(() => isLoading = false);
  }
}
```

error code :

> A value of type 'List (where IRLNews is defined in
> c:\src\flutter apps\newsapp\lib\classes\IRLNews.dart)' can't be
> assigned to a variable of type 'List (where IRLNews is
> defined in c:\src\flutter apps\newsapp\lib\classes\IRLnews.dart)'. Try
> changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to
> 'List (where IRLNews is defined in c:\src\flutter
> apps\newsapp\lib\classes\IRLnews.dart)'.

If i add a cast to the result of the readAllNews method, when i try to run the app, it wont load the news saying that :

> _CastError (type 'IRLNews' is not a subtype of type 'IRLNews' in type cast where   IRLNews is from package:wwe_universe/classes/IRLNews.dart
> IRLNews is from package:wwe_universe/classes/IRLnews.dart )

Can you help me see what I'm missing here please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have wrong import in `readAllNews` method. I see that there are two files
in `lib\classes` folder named `IRLNews.dart` and `IRLnews.dart`. Check that you imported correct file.

Like this:

in `readAllNews` method file:

if import is like this,

```
import 'package:wwe_universe/classes/IRLnews.dart';
```

also in your home screen, same import should be used.

Otherwise, if the import is like this,

```
import 'package:wwe_universe/classes/IRLNews.dart';
```

in your home screen also same import should be used.

Comment: Thank you ! That was the problem, didn't show me an error though so I would have never imagined the error was coming from the imports

Comment: You're welcome. That's a common issue when you have ambiguous file names. Cheers